# Prefab AudioSuorce not playing

Tags: unity-game-engine

I want to be able to switch background music depending on events in my game.

My solution:
Create 2 AudioSource objects and make these into a prefab:
[image: AudioSource1 prefab]

I added 2 AudioSource SerializeField to the camera script:

```
public class CameraScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] AudioSource audioSource1;
    [SerializeField] AudioSource audioSource2;
```

Back in the editor, I attached the AudioSource prefabs to the camera:
[image: Camera]

And the music is initiated in the camera script:

```
void Start()
    {
        audioSource1.Play();
    }
```

However, no music is playing.

Comment: Do you have a listener?

Comment: Yes, a camera is assigned a listener by defualt.

Comment: A prefab is only a **template** for an object ... if these are not spawned (= instantiated) into the actual scene they can not participate in your rendering or audio output => produce any sound at all ... you need to have them in your scene ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The audio source prefabs must be instantiated to be used:

```
[SerializeField] AudioSource pfAudioSource1;
[SerializeField] AudioSource pfAudioSource2;
AudioSource audioSource1;
AudioSource audioSource2;

void Start()
    {
        audioSource1 = Instantiate(pfAudioSource1);
        audioSource2 = Instantiate(pfAudioSource2);
        audioSource1.Play();
    }
```

Comment: Why not simply have these objects in your scene right away?

Comment: No good reason I guess. I wanted the audio to be fully controlled from code without linking it to a specific scene, but I don't have enough experience with unity to be certain that this is a good pattern.

Comment: `without linking it to a specific scene` by calling `Instantiate` they **are** spawned into the currently active scene ;)

Comment: Yes, that's the goal. Define the prefabs as a general asset, and not have to add it to each and every scene, instead loading it dynamically when the scene loads.